# Android Instant Apps: When clicking on a url link I see instant apps loading screen, but then just opens it in browser?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an instant app that was working when instant apps was first released. I dunno what happened along the way, but when I click on a url link it opens up the instant apps loading screen, then just quits and opens the link in the browser instead.

It works if you install the instant app from Android Studio directly on your phone, but not when uploaded into production to the Google Play Store.

Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs after you tap on the url? Is your device pre-O or O+?

Comment: @TWL I do see this in the logs, `E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.realtimeinstaller.l.onFinished(38): Install session failed`. I am on a O+ device (Google Pixel).

Comment: I suggest you to file a bug to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: any luck on this issue? I'm seeing it myself on something I'm working on.

Comment: @armadib no luck, but im gonna revisit this issue soon.. have you had any progress in trying to figure it out?